# Different form fields with different user group selection

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

In joomal 2.5 I have added a field to select user group in user registration field. While selecting each user group i need registration form with different fields.  I can’t purchase any commercial modules or components for this. Could anyone suggest a good solution for this? 
Thank you

Comment: How you add new field in reg ? by customizing code then you can do the rest too that way but joomla updation may cause issue

Comment: I have added user group by editing components\com_users\models\forms\registration.xml and components/com_user/models/registeration.php. I am not sure how to add extra fields and save it in database user table

Comment: Then you can create another table for managing the user details and add fields in the xml.keep the user_id relation for new table This will not an issue for joomla update.If you add fields in user table at the time of joomla update It may lost.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this by adding new field in registration.xml and $data['new_ field] = $data['new_ field]; in registeration.php. I also added a new field in user table. Field appears in registration form but I m not able to save this detail in database.

Comment: I also need to change registration form fields with respect to user group selection

Comment: in the registration model you can find one function if(!$user->save()) write an else part and put your query in extra function if you need but careful for update time..

Comment: Ok i will try this. Thank you for your quick suggestions.

Comment: Thank you jobin I tried this.  Only added field in xml and $data['academic_inst_name'] = $data['academic_inst_name'];  in register function. At that time my entry is saved in database. Thank you for your advice. Could you please help me in changing the fields with respect to user group selection?

Answer (score 0):

I think You are looking for something like this

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

Its time consuming but as per joomla standards.

Comment: Yes but i need different fields for different user groups

Comment: Please note that last line in that doc you can achieve that!

Comment: By changing fields you should javascript or jquery to hide and show corresponding fields.

Comment: yes i know this. But we are adding fields through xml so it will be not possible to add js functions in a xml file.

Comment: During the first load of registration default page based on select box value can you hide some fields using js file  ? Then you achieved.In xml all the fields are there no issue,But in the form you see only corresponding fields based on the select box value

Comment: Thank you Jobin my issue is fixed.